# Unpivot table from visuals in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, unpivot

I have a table in my report view and I am trying to display percentages based on location. How can I transform the first table in this image to the second format? If I used unpivot columns in Power Query I will miss up my other visuals. I still need to display more questions in front of each location so it would look ugly if I kept it like this.

Thanks[image]

Comment: transpose the table?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you need to `Demote Headers` before transposing.

### Steps

1. Demote headers, see image below:

[image]

2. Transpose Table

[image]

3. Finally, you need to `Promote Headers`.

### Power Query

Ignore Source, that's the data coming from the functionality `Enter Data`.

```
let
  Source = Table.FromRows(
    Json.Document(
      Binary.Decompress(
        Binary.FromText(
          "i45W8k3MzFMozixJVdJRMjQAEqYGqmAmkIrViVZyKkrMS85QMASJgQgzc5C0hRmKrBFQyBKITUxBkuZAJbGxAA==", 
          BinaryEncoding.Base64
        ), 
        Compression.Deflate
      )
    ), 
    let
      _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true])
    in
      type table [Location = _t, Total = _t, Question4 = _t, Question5 = _t]
  ), 
  #"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(Source), 
  #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Demoted Headers"), 
  #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars = true])
in
  #"Promoted Headers"
```

### Output

| Location | Main site | Branch 1 | Branch 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Total | 10 | 11 | 9 |
| Question4 | 50% | 67% | 45% |
| Question5 | 100% | 86% | 77% |